# Modelagem de Banco de Dados (Modelo Entidade Relacionamento)

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web

Na imagem abaixo tem a modelagem do seguinte problema.
Tenho usuários onde estes vão pertencer a módulos(Modulo física, modulo português, modulo química) são 3 módulos no total.UM e apenas UM (1) dos módulos pode conter de 1 à n grupos, esses grupos são formados por usuários e cada grupo contém apenas 1 Administrador.

Na tabela usuário uso um atributo para dizer se o usuário é ADM de algum grupo.

A minha dúvida é em relação a modelagem que fiz, percebam que ela está circular. Alguém tem uma forma melhor de modelar esse problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O relacionamente direto entre usuário e módulo não é estritamente necessário, já que pode ser inferido pela participação do usuário em um grupo que pertença a determinado módulo. Mas também não é errado, pode até ser que suas regras de negócio exijam essa redundância – por exemplo, a inscrição em um módulo ocorre em um momento anterior à formação dos grupos.

Answer (score 1):

Não existe um padrão para o formato da modelagem, agora esta faltando identificação do relacionamento entre as entidades, ai sim existem boas práticas para identificá-las como: id_grupo para uma chave estrangeira da entidade grupo ou id_modulo para chave estrangeira da entidade modulo.